# Quickfix client for Rapid Addition engine

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

My FIX server is using Rapid Addition engine, can I use use QuickFIX client code to connect to my FIX server which is on Rapid Addition?

I think it should be able to connect since client can be on any technology but not sure whether this really correct. So it would be good if someone could confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

The FIX protocol is (or rather should be) entirely independent of the the API used. Using QuickFIX I have connected to Rapid addition and many other proprietary FIX engines and they all work as expected. The only issue that you might have is if the FIX engine has SSL embedded in it but then stunnel can be used to allow communications.